# Is it possible to get Angular2 and D3.js working together?

Tags: d3.js, angular

By working together I mean that I can place Angular bindings in D3.js code, perhaps

```
    .attr("bind-attr.fill", "aColorVar")
```

where aColorVar is a variable that can be also bound to a color control in Angular way.

I can do similar things in Angular1, unfortunately using $compile.
I can bind SVG attributes when SVG is used as a component template.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in Angular 2 we can only setup bindings in templates, not in code, so I can't think of a way to get this to work.

The best I can think of is to put the D3 code into a component or a directive, then you can use the component/directive properties:

```
.attr("fill", this.someComponentProperty)
```

However, this does not setup any kind of binding.  If you update property `someComponentProperty`, you will need to execute that line of code again.

Comment: This attribute will not update.  
The "fill" value is simply the value of this.someComponentProperty in the moment of the graph creation.

Comment: @Yanek, right, I didn't mean to imply otherwise.  I guess I should have been more clear... if you need to update the attribute, you have to run that line of code again.  I'll update the answer.